# Why is it recommended to save viewstate values in the PreRender event call?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to persist member variables by saving them in the ViewState (only a few small variables) however I read up and I gather its better to save them into the ViewState at the PreRender stage than PageLoad?

I can see that the ViewState can be saved to anytime before Page rendering, but does it make any difference in PreRender or PageLoad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a difference.  You just need to save your variables to the ViewState after you are finished changing them.  i.e.  Don't save the variable to the ViewState in the Page_Load event if you change it again in PreRender.